# remove duplicate number in array in c

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, duplicates

**I want my output print the array without any duplicate number**

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    #define BUBBLE 5
    int main()
    {
        int myArray[BUBBLE];
        int i, j ,a , b, k;
        int temp = 0;
        int num;
        int cunt, size;
        cunt=0;
        float floatType;
        int integerType;



    srand(time(NULL));
```

> make the array randomlly

```
    //Fill Array Randomlly
    for (i = 0; i < BUBBLE; i ++)
    {    
           num = rand() % BUBBLE + 1;
           myArray[i] = num;
    }
```

> here my problem is not working
>   *in the program tell me*
>    **Error value required as decrement operand**

```
 for (a = 0; i < BUBBLE; a++) {
          for (b = a + 1; j < BUBBLE;) {
             if (myArray[i] == myArray[i]) {
                for (k = b; k < BUBBLE; k++) {
                    myArray[k] =  myArray[k + 1];
                }
                BUBBLE --;
             } else
                b++;
          }
       }
```

> Sort Array With Bobble Algorhim
>
> here my sort

for(i = 0; i < BUBBLE; i++)
    {

```
    for (j = 0; j < BUBBLE-1; j++)
    {
        if (myArray[j] > myArray[j+1])
        {
            temp = myArray[j];
            myArray[j] = myArray[j+1];
            myArray[j+1] = temp;

            cunt++;
            }
        }/*End inner for loop*/
    }/*End outer for loop*/
```

> the output

```
    //Print Array After Sort
    for (i = 0; i < BUBBLE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",myArray[i]);

    }
    // Count For How Many Swap
         printf("the numbeer of pases is %d \n" ,cunt);
          printf("Size of float: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(floatType));
           printf("Size of int: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(integerType));
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}/*End of main*/
```

Comment: You don't have to sort to do that. Go through each number and check if appeared before, if it did not, print it otherwise ignore and move on to the next number.

Comment: @Abdulrhman A. Al-mulhim  You may not change the value of the integer constant BUBBLE --;

Answer (score 1):

You may not change integer constants. At the compile-time this code snippet

```
 for (a = 0; i < BUBBLE; a++) {
          for (b = a + 1; j < BUBBLE;) {
             if (myArray[i] == myArray[i]) {
                for (k = b; k < BUBBLE; k++) {
                    myArray[k] =  myArray[k + 1];
                }
                BUBBLE --;
             } else
                b++;
          }
       }
```

actually looks like

```
 for (a = 0; i < 5; a++) {
          for (b = a + 1; j < 5;) {
             if (myArray[i] == myArray[i]) {
                for (k = b; k < 5; k++) {
                    myArray[k] =  myArray[k + 1];
                }
                5--;
                ^^^
             } else
                b++;
          }
       }
```

That is the compiler substitutes the name `BUBBLE` for the integer constant `5`.

Moreover it is unclear where for example the variables `i` and `j` are initialized. And this condition in the if statement

```
if (myArray[i] == myArray[i]) {
           ^^^           ^^^
```

does not make sense.

You should declare a variable that will keep the actual number of elements in the array during deleting duplicates because you can not change the size of an already initialized array.

"Removing" duplicates can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUBBLE  5

int main(void) 
{
    int a[BUBBLE] = { 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < BUBBLE; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < BUBBLE; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;

        while ( j < i && a[j] != a[i] ) ++j;

        if ( j == i )
        {
            if ( n != i ) a[n] = a[i];
            ++n;
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 1 3 2 
1 2 3
```

The variable `n` keeps the actual number of elements of the array after removing duplicates.